# how to calculate the distance using Pos haskell

Tags: haskell

Say I defined this type:
type Pos = (Int, Int)

I'd like to use above type to calculate thhe distance between two points, and I wrote like this:

```
type Pos = (Int, Int)
distancee :: Pos -> Pos -> Float
distancee Pos (x1,y1) (x2,y2) = sqrt((dx*dx)+(dy*dy))
    where
        dx = x2 - x1
        dy = y2 - y1
```

I dont really know how to use Pos, and above is not right, so could you please tell me how can I fix that?

Comment: This is basically right, you've just got to convert dx and dy to Float.

Comment: Change `distancee Pos (x1,y1) (x2,y2)` to `distancee (x1,y1) (x2,y2)`

Answer (score 5):

There are two problems here. The first one is that a `Point` is a type alias for a 2-tuple. It thus has no specific data constructor. This means that the head of the `distancee` should look like:

```
type Pos = (Int, Int)

distancee :: Pos -> Pos -> Float
distancee (x1,y1) (x2,y2) = …
```

A second problem is that subtracting two `Int`s results in an `Int`, multiplying two `Int`s results in an `Int`, and adding two `Int`s together will produce an `Int`. This is because the [`(-) :: Num a => a -> a -> a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-45-), [`(*) :: Num a => a -> a -> a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-42-), and  [`(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-43-) all have a signature where the two operands and the result all have the same type. We can not apply  [`sqrt :: Floating a => a -> a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:sqrt) for an `Int`, since it requires a type that is a member of the `Floating` typeclass. We can make use of [**`fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromIntegral) to convert an item of an `Integral` type into an object of a `Num` type with:

```
distancee :: Pos -> Pos -> Float
distancee (x1,y1) (x2,y2) = sqrt (fromIntegral (dx*dx + dy*dy))
    where dx = x2 - x1
          dy = y2 - y1
```